# System.out.print wont let me have two seperate lines

Tags: java

I am trying to create an array of 5 numbers. When the user inputs these numbers, i want the system to print them out. Then i want to swap the first and last number and print out the new line of numbers. Ive tried a few ways to get them on different lines and nothing will work.
The out put i want would look something like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
5 2 3 4 1
```

Here is the code i have so far

```
import java.util.*;
public class arraySwap 
{  
    public static void main (String[]args)  
    {   
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array[] = new int[5];  
        int firstNum = 0;  
        int lastNum = 0;  
        int temp = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++)   {
            array[i] = scan.nextInt();   
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++)   {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
            System.out.println(breakline);   
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++)   {
            firstNum = array[0]; //1
            lastNum = array[4]; //5
            temp = firstNum; //1
            array[0] = lastNum;
            array[4] = firstNum;
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");   
        } 
     }
}
```

Comment: Remove the line `System.out.println(breakline);` and add a `System.out.println();` just before the last `for-loop`.

Comment: Insert `System.out.println()` just before the last `for loop`.

Comment: @SubOptimal that works! thank you. It was so easy i feel like a moron now

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach can be

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array[] = new int[5];   
        int temp = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)   {
            array[i] = scan.nextInt();   
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)   {
           System.out.print(array[i] + " ");   
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print(array[array.length-1] + " ");
        for(int i = 1; i < array.length-1; i++)   {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");   
        } 

        System.out.print(array[0] + " ");
        System.out.println();


        // or
        // swap first, then print all the elements
        int temp = array[0];  
        array[0] = array[array.length-1];
        array[array.length-1] = temp;



        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)   {
           System.out.print(array[i] + " ");   
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the System.out.println() in the end of the first `for loop`.

```
import java.util.*;
public class arraySwap 
{  
    public static void main (String[]args)  
    {   
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array[] = new int[5];  
        int firstNum = 0;  
        int lastNum = 0;  
        int temp = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++)   {
            array[i] = scan.nextInt();   
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++)   {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
            // System.out.println(breakline); <-- Remove this..
        }
        System.out.println(); // Place it here, without the 'breakline' arg.
        for(int i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++)   {
            firstNum = array[0]; //1
            lastNum = array[4]; //5
            temp = firstNum; //1
            array[0] = lastNum;
            array[4] = firstNum;
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");   
        } 
     }
}
```

`System.out.println()` is equivalent to a new line.